# Can you put html output inside of a javascript function? Tried to make php variable and insert that into JS function, but no luck

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I worked on a method tonight that allowed me to make hidden div's and then use .text() with jQuery to get the contents of the hidden div, but now I am stuck with a similar scenario. You can see my original question here: [How can you put PHP inside a Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233676/how-can-you-put-php-inside-a-javascript)

Basically, I have a script to get Google+ followers, which works great:

```
<script>
var profileid = 'xxx';
 var apikey = 'xxx';
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/' + profileid + '?key=' + apikey;
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
url: url,
success: function (data) {
    var googlefollowcount = data.circledByCount;
  $(".googleFollowerCount").html(googlefollowcount.toLocaleString('en'));
}
});
</script>
```

I tried to the result into a PHP variable, which does echo out nicely, and also tried the "hidden div" method to later extract it into a JS function, you can see both attempts here (both which print the correct follower number on a page):

```
<?php $goCount = "<span class='googleFollowerCount'></span>";
echo "goCount is: $goCount";
?>
<div id="googlePlusCountHiddenDiv"><?php echo $goCount; ?></div>
```

And here's the problem, I can't get that number into this JS function (I made an alert, and it returns NaN):

```
var goCount = parseInt($("#googlePlusCountHiddenDiv").text());
alert(goCount);
$({someValue: 0}).animate({someValue: goCount}, {
duration: 3000,
easing: 'swing',
step: function () {
   $('#googlePlusCount').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
},
complete:function(){
      $('#googlePlusCount').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
  }
});
```

The whole  seems to be going into the JS code, when what I want is the number that  prints on the screen.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: What do you get when you run `console.log($("#googlePlusCountHiddenDiv").text())`

Comment: A blank alert popup, and then after closing that, a "NaN" where the number should be on the screen.

Comment: The console says "empty string"

Comment: When I view source, I believe I see the "issue", here is the php printing out the goCount and then the hidden div: `goCount is: <span class='googleFollowerCount'></span>    <div id="googlePlusCountHiddenDiv"><span class='googleFollowerCount'></span></div>` you can see that the "number" isn't in the actual source, and although I see the number on the screen, it's the actual HTML being passed into that JS function.

Comment: Still working on this... I think I've narrowed it down to I can't get the $goCount value to appear here, maybe a quotes issue? Things I've tried: alert("<?php echo '<span class="googleFollowerCount"></span>'; ?>");  and alert('<?php echo $goCount; ?>'); and alert('<?php $goCount = "<span class='googleFollowerCount'></span>"; echo '$goCount;' ?>');

Comment: You load the follower count via AJAX, its loaded asynchronously, your script  tries to parse it before its actually there, you animation code should be in the `success` callback of your googleapis query. PS: Dont post code in comments, its not readable, edit your question instead.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, that was it!! I had to put that animation code in the success callback, just like you said. And, I will remember to edit my code too, sorry about that, I'm new to this and gratefully appreciate all the help you and the experts have given me! thanks again, got it working (took a day or so, but hey, it works!!!)